# Why do we have only one DNA?

Tags: dna-rna

I've been crossed a very interesting thought..
Why is it that our body has only single form of DNA, and what would happen if we had multiple forms of DNA?

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple forms of DNA"? In what way would/should they differ from the current version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have just one type of DNA, because humans develop from a single cell. This single cell contains only type of DNA and cell division makes exact copies of it. Since humans (and basically all other organisms) form by cell division, they therefore have to have the same one type of DNA as the first cell.

The question then is, why should the first cell have only one type of DNA. This is probably because the molecules of DNA "float" freely in the nucleus and having two different "types" of DNA could lead to some weird interactions between the different types.

It would be possible, theoretically, to have more nuclei, each with a different type of DNA, but I don't really see why any organism would want to do that. It would make genetic errors much more probable and it seems that all organisms live all right with just one type of DNA.

*I write "a different type of DNA", but what I really mean (and what I think you also meant) is "a different way of storing genetic information". In a way, humans have two different ways of doing that - RNA and DNA, but only DNA is used for long-term storage, since it is more stable.

A different way could be to e. g. use a different molecule than DNA, maybe different bases than A, C, G, T; or use a different sugar than (deoxy-)ribose or maybe a different link than the phosphate groups. This makes for a very exciting field of study (and I think the part with more bases has already been done somewhere.)